# remove_action() not working in page template - Genesis

Tags: php, functions, actions, page-template

I've had a good look around but can't find anyone with the same specific problem.

In *functions.php* I'm adding the following actions:

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'twl_content_wrap_start', 15 );
function twl_content_wrap_start() {
    echo '<div class="container">';
}

add_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'twl_content_wrap_end', 15 );
function twl_content_wrap_end() {
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Then in my Page Template *page_full-width.php*, I'm trying to remove these actions.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'twl_content_wrap_start', 15 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'twl_content_wrap_end', 15 );
```

But it's not working!

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: From the looks of it, it should work, unless you are removing the actions after they have already fired.

Comment: @VladOlaru Do you think I need to wrap them in another action to make sure they fire before the add_actions in functions.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page templates are called too late to effect actions. You can achieve what you need another way, by targeting this in your functions, with a test for the page template, like this:

```
function twl_content_wrap_start() {
    if ( !is_page_template( "page_full-width.php" ) )
        return '<div class="container">';
}
```

BTW, as a rule of thumb, actions generally don't `echo`, they should `return` (although it does depend on the action).

Comment: Thanks! That's worked and I've switch to a return. The echo came from many tutorials online :/ What's strange is the Genesis child theme uses remove_action() in files like page.php and single.php. Is it just custom Page templates where this won't work?